# lodash map skip iteration

Tags: arrays, iteration, lodash

i can't seem to find a way to skip an iteration using the lodash _.map, consider this array: `checklist =['first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth']`
i want to map through it with a step of 3 for example, i tried this code but it didn't work:

```
    _.map(checkList, function(value, key){
  console.log('checkList', firstValue);
console.log('checkList1', secondValue);
console.log('checkList2', thirdValue);
}, 3)
```

expected output : `checkList first , checkList second, checkList third, checkList fourth, checkList fifth, checkList sixth`
but only with two iterations

something i can achieve using for like this:

```
    for(let i = 0; i< checkList.length; i+=3){
  console.log('value', checkList[i]);
  console.log('value1', checkList[i+1]);
  console.log('value2', checkList[i+2]);
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map, filter, forEach, reduce, etc... iterate all items in the array, and you can't skip items. For this tasks, a `for` loop is quite fitting.

If you want to achieve that with lodash, use [`_.chunk()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk) to split the array into sub arrays with the required size, and then iterate using [`_.forEach()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach) (or map, filter, etc...).

```js
var checklist = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth'];

_(checklist)
  .chunk(3)
  .forEach(function(subArr) {
     console.log('checkList', subArr[0]);
     console.log('checkList1', subArr[1]);
     console.log('checkList2', subArr[2]);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, i expected this, but the problem is that you can't use for loop inside JSX in React

Comment: You can use the for loop inside a function, and invoke it inside the JSX.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about two different operations - one to take each third item and one to transform them. `.map` transforms *all* items in the input and I'm not sure why you assume passing a `3` into it would do what you're describing.

To do what you're describing, filter the items first, then map them:

```js
var checkList = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth'];
var thirdItems = _.filter(checkList, function(v, i) {  return i % 3 === 1; });
var result = _.map(thirdItems, function(value, key) { return 'checkList ' + value; });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but this is not what i wanted, i edited my question

Comment: @EliasGhali Well I'm sure you can pardon my misunderstanding because your original question has almost nothing to do with your current question, and I answered your original question.